# How to store cooked Quinoa for few hours at work?

Tags: storage, quinoa

I want to cook red grain quinoa while making breakfast at home in the morning, and then pack it and have it later for lunch at work with a salad. How should I store it after cooking for about 5 hours?

More details: 
I'm planning to cook it and immediately put it in a plastic container, then go to work (travel time: 15 minutes) and then keep it in a refrigerator at work. Then re-heat in a microwave for 20 seconds at lunchtime and consume hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try to first bring hot quinoa to room temperature and follow the rest which you already mentioned. That works great, else if you try to pack it when it like burning hot, then the steam kind of stays in the packed room which later creates moisture and later spoils the food even though you keep it in the refrigerator.

Best worked for me is by cooking quinoa in the night. Now I have lot of time to bring it to room temperature followed by pack it, store it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Any sealed container for room temperature Red Quinoa to refrigerator-be it plastic storage, bowls with plastic wrapping; have all worked excellent for me.  Red Quinoa is always the best in terms of separating and not clumping-which was my experience with Pearl Quinoa.